# SQL Server - How to select record where my value in split column

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, split

This is result that I want:

[image]

I wrote a stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[test_Split] 
    @item INT
AS
    CREATE TABLE #temp
    (
         Id INT, 
         Name NVARCHAR(50), 
         List NVARCHAR(100)
    )

    INSERT INTO #temp 
    VALUES (1, 'John', '1,2,4,6,7'), (2, 'Fox', '7,23,42,10,17'),
           (3, 'Rose', '51,72,14,16,37'), (4, 'Alex', '1,22,84,56,47')

    SELECT * 
    FROM #temp
```

When I execute `test_Split`, I get the results shown in the screenshot.

When I pass `@item = 1` (any number), I want to get result like the right part of the screenshot (`List` column include my value).

Is there any way to do this without a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
where List like + '%' + @item + '%'
```

So...

```
select * 
from #temp
where List like + '%' + @item + '%'
```

Notice this will find all rows where 1 is present. The only hack to distinguish between 1 and numbers like 15 is to search for a comma.

```
select * 
from #temp
where 
List like + '%,' + @item + ',%'
or List like + @item + ',%'
or List like + '%,' + @item
```

It's much wiser to use a split function and `INNER JOIN`. 
 I'd check out [Jeff's article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993).

Comment: I was thinking this way but when `List` include value `11` or other bumber include `1` value.

Comment: See my edit @M.Rashford. Specifically the last query

Comment: I was read your update. I try make `List ` column have at least  1 `,` characters =))

Comment: Sounds good. The function link I provided is really good as well if you aren't on 2016 yet

Comment: I using 2014 version !